# div on same page with float option mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using a div structure to print pdf using mPDF. I want to bind a div on same page and if space not available on the same page then the whole section should come on next page. 
I am using float for divs to design. Below is sample for one div section

```
<div class="action_div">    
<div style="width: 100%;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;font-size: 12px;font-family: segoe;font-weight: bold;">
    <div style="width: 10%;float:left;text-align: center;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="width: 90%;float:left;">
        <?php echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>. <?php echo $hazard['name'] ?>
    </div> 
</div>  
<div style="width: 100%;background-color: #EBECEC;padding-top: 8px;padding-bottom: 8px;font-size: 12px;font-family: segoe;border-bottom: 1px dotted #939598;border-top: 1px dotted #939598;font-weight: bold;">
    <div style="width: 10%;float:left;text-align: center;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="width: 90%;float:left;">
        Top 3 Control Measure
    </div> 
</div>  
<?php 
$j=1; foreach($hazard['pie_char_arr'] as $action){ ?>
<div style="width: 100%;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;font-size: 12px;font-family: segoe;border-bottom: 1px dotted #939598;">
    <div style="width: 15%;float:left;text-align: center;">
        <?php echo str_pad($j, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 85%;float:left;">
        <?php echo $action['action'] ?>
    </div> 
</div> 
<?php if($j==3){
        break;
    }
    $j++;} ?>
```

this section is coming in a loop. Also content can vary for $action['action'] and for $hazard['name']. Can not use pagebreak after each loop as it can show a blank page with a very few data on that.

Answer (score 2):

mPDF has basic support for the `page-break-inside: avoid` CSS property ([see documentation of all supported CSS](http://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)), but its been my experience that this doesn't work well (if at all) for floated elements. If it works, it's an easy win:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    <!-- Contents -->
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, you can break your HTML content up into smaller chunks and write each block a section at a time:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($chunk1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($chunk2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($chunk3);
```

Between chunks you can check where the current Y pointer is on the page using `$mpdf->y`, then force a page break if there isn't enough room for your chunk:

```
if ($mpdf->y > 150) { // if the Y pointer is lower than 150mm on the page
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak />');
}
```

This method requires you can 1. break your HTML into smaller chunks and 2. know how large your chunk is (or at least a good approximation).

For truly dynamic content, the most foolproof method I've found is cloning the Mpdf object before writing each chunk and checking if `count($mpdf->pages)` has increased. [I recommend the myclabs/DeepCopy library](https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy) ([a package that will be rolled into mPDF in a future update](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/pull/667)). If the array increases, your chunk won't fit on a single page and you'll need to add a page break:

```
$copier = new DeepCopy\DeepCopy(true);
$MpdfClone = $copier->copy($mpdf);
$currentPageCount = count($MpdfClone->pages);
$currentPageCount = $currentPageCount !== 0 ? $currentPageCount : 1; //fix when the object is first created and no pages have been added
$MpdfClone->WriteHTML($chunk);

if ($currentPageCount !== count($MpdfClone->pages)) {
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak />');
}

unset($MpdfClone);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($chunk);
```

There is a lot of overhead when writing a lot of chunks to a PDF using this method. I recommend running your own benchmarks before deciding to implement this technique.